# Comparar y Ordenar 2 archivos Json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, web

Me gustaría la ayuda de alguien para realizar la comparación y ordenación de 2 archivos: .JSON ( cada archivo contiene mas casi 4000 lineas al visualizar en el notepad++)

Me explico :

**Archivo1.json** (imaginar que este arquivo tiene su contenido todo en portugués después del 2 puntos ( : ))

```
 var PT = {
    "xxx.yyy.Masculino": "Masculino",
    "yyy.yyy.Femenino": "Feminino",
    "yyy.yyy.Sexo_no_informado": "Sex"
              }
```

**Archivo2.json**  (imaginar que este arquivo tiene su contenido todo en inglés después del 2 puntos ( : ))

```
var ING = {
    "yyy.yyy.Femenino": "Fem",
    "xxx.yyy.Masculino": "Muscle",
    "yyy.yyy.Sexo": "Sex"
         }
```

Observación1: Si se fijan bien, los códigos ( al lado izquierdo de los 2 puntos, ejemplo: "yyy.yyy.Femenino" ) se encuentran no en el mismo orden secuencial entre los archivos.

Observación2: Necesito que me muestren en caso los códigos sean iguales los 2 valores ( PT y ING) .

```
Ejemplo:  "xxx.yyy.Masculino": "Masculino", " Musculino " //son iguales no debo traducir
          "yyy.yyy.Femenino": "Feminino", "Fem" //distinto, debo traducir
```

La idea es poder verificar de forma más fácil, las diferencias para saber si debo traducir ese campo o no.

Alguna idea de como realizar esto de forma automática? 
Ya que realizar esto Linea por Linea pierdo mucho tiempo.
Desde ya quedo agradecido.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, ¿has intentado algo? Creo que lo primero que se tiene que hacer es almacenar ambos objetos en una variable de tipo `dynamic`, luego, tomar como base una y buscar el código en la otra por medio de Linq, ahí es donde validas si son iguales o diferentes.

Comment: @Flxtr Buenas tardes.... no soy programador.... me gustaría aprender, soy traductor de idiomas... pero quiero hacer de esta necesidad un desafío.
¿Cuál lenguaje me orientas que sea más simples?

Comment: En lo personal te recomendaría C#, para mí es bastante intuitivo, sencillo de usar y hay montones de tutoriales y documentación por todo el internet. Por ejemplo, Microsoft tiene su propia academia virutal y muchos cursos gratuitos, por ejemplo, [este](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169), [acá](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfkTfcpWqAY) puedes encontrar otro y entre más le busques más le encuentras ;)

Comment: @LuisFernando Me gustaría entender la aplicación, me llama la atención aprender a programar para crear mis propias herramientas , pero mi necesidad es de urgencia ....

Comment: @Flxtr para trabajar con JSON es mejor o mas facil usar C# o JavaScript? Tu opinion

Comment: Sin duda alguna C#

Comment: @Flxtr siendo super sincero contigo, creo que Javascript, no por conocer el lenguaje ( ya que no se absolutamente nada de Javascript) pero porque conozco personas que trabajan con eso y me podrian orientar mas en caso de dudas de código. Tengo nociones básicas de programación (if, for, do while, case , while ). Puedo entender algo el código pero no 100%. Creo que me entiendes.

Comment: Me pueden orientar como empezar por C# entonces para manipular Json?

Comment: Claro, te entiendo a la perfección. Mi respuesta se basa en que para el caso de C# ya existen librerías para el manejo de json, por ejemplo Newtonsoft. Te simplifican mucho el trabajo y no hay que reinventar el hilo negro. Ayuda mucho que conozcas y te acomodes con un lenguaje, sobretodo si ese  lenguaje es de yu preferencia

Comment: Yo te puedo ayudar, solo que ando lejos de una computadora, dame unos minutos y hacemos un ejemplo en vivo y a todo color

Comment: @Flxtr, tengo el Visual Studio en el computador de mi casa descargado.
Soy de mente abierta, no me cierro a un lenguaje.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66895/discussion-between-rodrigo-hackz-exploitz-and-flxtr).

Comment: las propiedades del json o sea el xxx.yyy puede ser dinamico, o se conoce y son fijos?

Comment: en los 2 archivos .Json  el código "xxx.yyy". es fijo, ejemplo:

"xxx.yyy.Color":"color",
"xxx.yyy.ENABLED": "Activo",

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria llevar los json a clases de `c#` en donde puedas trabajar ocn linq para unir la info

Lo que si deberas asegurar es que ambos tengan las misma propiedades, o sea si uno define `yyy.yyy.Sexo_no_informado` y el otro json `yyy.yyy.Sexo` esto no va a poder ser igualado

Entonces defines la clase en base al json ayudandote con

http://json2csharp.com/

obteniendo

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string xxx.yyy.Masculino { get; set; }
    public string yyy.yyy.Femenino { get; set; }
}
```

la idea es que usando json.net

[Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

deserializas el json a la clase

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string  PTJson = "{\"xxx_yyy_Masculino\": \"Masculino\", \"yyy_yyy_Femenino\": \"Feminino\", \"yyy_yyy_Sexo_no_informado\": \"Sex\" }";

        RootObject PT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(PTJson);

        string  INGJson = "{\"yyy_yyy_Femenino\": \"Fem\", \"xxx_yyy_Masculino\": \"Muscle\", \"yyy.yyy.Sexo\": \"Sex\" }";

        RootObject ING = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(INGJson);


        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("xxx_yyy_Masculino = {0} {1}", PT.xxx_yyy_Masculino, ING.xxx_yyy_Masculino) );
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("yyy_yyy_Femenino = {0} {1}", PT.yyy_yyy_Femenino, ING.yyy_yyy_Femenino));


    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string xxx_yyy_Masculino { get; set; }
        public string yyy_yyy_Femenino { get; set; }
    }


}
```

como veras puedes obtener los valores de cada json para comparalos entre si

Nota: no es valido usar punto como nombre de propiedad, por eso reemplace por `_`

Comment: C# no acepta como tal el nombre de variables con `.`, por lo que se tendría que optar por otra solución, a lo mejor declarar la clase sin los `.` y al obtener el json limpiarlo y quitarle dichos puntos.